# ffmpeg video is skewed from audio?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have the code below but when completed the video is slow or faster than the audio

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -af "[0:a]volume=5.2, bandreject=f=900:width_type=h:w=600, bandreject=f=900:width_type=h:w=600" -filter_complex "crop=in_w/1.1:in_h/1.1:(in_w-out_w)/1.1+((in_w-out_w)/1.1)*sin(t*1.2):(in_h-out_h)/1.1 +((in_h-out_h)/1.1)*sin(t*1.2), zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(on,161),92),zoom+0.568,zoom-5)':d=1:x='(iw-(iw/zoom))*(1011/1024)':y='(ih-(ih/zoom))*(568/576)':s=1280x720" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 22 -g 60 -b:v 2600k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -vol 256 -ar 44100  -preset ultrafast "output.mp4"
```

Can you help me?

> info video
>   [https://imgur.com/YFG45VP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsKrw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That is because default zoompan filter output fps is 25, change it to fps of your input to zoompan filter.

Comment: Can you fix it for me?
I don't know much about this

Comment: Without frame rate of input video it can not be fixed.

Comment: I have added the video information above.
Can you edit the command line for me?